# validate the datas and echo the valid data to index file

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to php wrapper class... Here i included the class file... I don't know to how to write insert query... Plz tell me how to write the insert query by using the below class...

```
class Database {

    public $connection;
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $dbname = "property";

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
        $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function insert($query, array $data) {
        $this->connection->prepare($query)->execute($data);
        return $this->connection->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function update($query, array $data) {
        $stmt = $this->executeQuery($query, $data);
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }

    public function delete($query, array $data) {
        $stmt = $this->executeQuery($query, $data);
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }

    public function findOne($query, array $data = null) {
        $stmt = $this->executeQuery($query, $data);
        return $stmt->fetchObject();
    }

    public function findMany($query, array $data = null) {
        $stmt = $this->executeQuery($query, $data);
        return($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
    }

    public function executeQuery($query, $data = null) {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($data);
        return $stmt;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `inset()` method, so use it

```
$db = new Database();
$lastId = $db->insert(
    'INSERT INTO `myTable` (`name`, `title`) VALUES (:name, :title)',
    [
        ':name' => 'Name of entry',
        ':title' => 'Title of entry',
    ],
);

var_dump($lastId);
```

Comment: @saravananam you are binding values in second `insert()` parameter passed as array. `array(':paramName' => $paramValue, ':param1' => $v1...)`

Comment: @saravananam From reading code everything is clear. It's simple PDO wrapper. Read code and check parameters of functions, that's it.

Comment: Actually i'm totally new to php and pdo wrapper class

Comment: require './Db.class.php';
    $db = new Database();
    $menus = $db->select('SELECT `tab_name` FROM `menutabs`');

Comment: @saravananam I will repeat myself - READ CODE. There is no method, named `select` in this wrapper class. And you can just throw that class and use simple PDO/mysqli_* functions

Comment: i am having error in the following code...                                                 $user_email_id = "saro@gmail.com"; // At real time read this from the session varables
$franchise_qur = $db->executeQuery("SELECT b.franchise_id FROM t_users a "
        . "RIGHT JOIN t_franchise b ON b.franchise_id=a.franchise_id "
        . "WHERE a.user_email_id=:user_email_id",[
            ':user_email_id' => $user_email_id
                ]);                                    $franchise_id = $franchise_qur[0]["franchise_id"];              echo $franchise_id;  i used pdo wrapper class...